# Unable to click button inside iframe with selenium webdriver (javascript)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, chrome-web-driver

I have a page that loads an iframe, but I get `NoSuchElementError` error messages.
My code:

```
driver.wait(until.ableToSwitchToFrame(0)).then((d) => {
  //*** SLEEP HERE
  const button = By.css(".button");
  driver.wait(until.elementLocated(dropdownElem)).then((btn) => {
    btn.click();
  });
});
```

First I switch to the correct iframe, then I try to wait for the element to load inside the iframe.
If I insert a `driver.sleep(1000);` to the line `//*** SLEEP HERE` it works, otherwise it fails with:

```
NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".button"
}
```

Why doesn't the `driver.wait` line waits for the element to become available?

Comment: have you tried [`waitUntil`](http://webdriver.io/api/utility/waitUntil.html) ?

Comment: I'm using selenium-webdriver nodejs bindings, the official maintained by selenium. The one you linked is webdriverIO, a different library.

Comment: @marchello, why did you tag the question as `webdriverio`-related?

Comment: @iamdanchiv, I wanted the `webdriver` tag. my mistake. corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this on my local and it seems to have worked fine for a button within Iframe. Here is the code

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().usingServer().withCapabilities({'browserName': 'chrome' }).build();
 driver.get('file:///Users/../sampleFiles/sample-iframe.html');
driver.wait(webdriver.until.ableToSwitchToFrame(0)).then((d) => {
  //*** SLEEP HERE
  const button = webdriver.By.css(".Button");
  driver.wait(webdriver.until.elementLocated(button)).then((btn) => {
    btn.click();
   btn.getTagName().then((tag) => { 
      console.log(tag);
    });
  });


});
```

I get `button` on console

and Iframe HTML this is tested on is

```
<html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example of HTML Iframe</title>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="file:///Users/../sampleFiles/sample.html" width="300" height="200">
        <html><head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<button id="ButtonID" class="Button">Click Me!</button>


</body></html>
    </iframe>

  </body></html>
```

Check your `driver.wait(until.elementLocated(dropdownElem))` line , seems theres a typo , change it to

`driver.wait(until.elementLocated(button ))`  and try again